# Regex: Don't match if match is inside a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match all the hashtags in a description. However URLs sometimes appear in descriptions and URLs can sometimes contain the hashtag symbol.

Using regex, how can I avoid selecting hashtags if they are part of a URL?

Additionally, if a hashtag starts with a digit I want to ignore it because it is most likely not a hashtag but a list item.

Here is my [current regex](https://regex101.com/r/9SSxdl/2):

```
(https?:\/\/\S+)|#(.*?)[\s]
```

It mostly does not work, it erroneously matches `#1`, `http://example.com/#urlpart` and `https://example.com#urlpart?s=search`.

Comment: Ok, I see you are using it in JavaScript, you should have mentioned that from the start. Now, what are you doing? Extracting? Replacing (wrapping with some tags?)? Splitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript solution:**

Match a URL and *match and capture* the hashtags that meet your requirements with

```
/https?:\/\/\S+|(#(?!\d)[^\s#]+)/ig
```

JS ***extraction*** demo:

```js
const s = "regular text\n\n#1 0:33 - Cool thing <-- this should not match\n\nTag 2 and tag 3 should be treated as seperate hashtags\n#tag1 #tag2#tag3 \n\nHashtags inside URLs should be ignored\n\nhttp://example.com/#urlpart\n\nhttps://example.com#urlpart?s=search";
const regex = /https?:\/\/\S+|(#(?!\d)[^\s#]+)/ig;
const matches = [...s.matchAll(regex)];
console.log( Array.from(matches, x => x[1]).filter(Boolean) );
```

JS ***replacement*** demo:

```js
const s = "regular text\n\n#1 0:33 - Cool thing <-- this should not match\n\nTag 2 and tag 3 should be treated as seperate hashtags\n#tag1 #tag2#tag3 \n\nHashtags inside URLs should be ignored\n\nhttp://example.com/#urlpart\n\nhttps://example.com#urlpart?s=search";
const regex = /https?:\/\/\S+|(#(?!\d)([^\s#]+))/ig;
console.log( s.replace(regex, (x,y,z) => y !== undefined ? `<a href="dir/${z}">${y}</a>` : `${x}` ) );
```

**PCRE Solution**

You may use

```
https?:\/\/\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|#(?!\d)[^\s#]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6ljTC/1)

**Details**

- `https?:\/\/\S+(*SKIP)(*F)` - match and skip URLs
- `|` - or
- `#(?!\d)[^\s#]+` - match and return substrings matching

  - `#` - a `#` char
  - `(?!\d)[^\s#]+` - any chunks of one or more chars other than `#` and whitespace not starting with a digit.

Comment: Trying to use `text.match(/https?:\/\/\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|#(?!\d)[^\s#]+/gm)` in javascript throws the error `VM2176:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat`.

Comment: @Nostupidquestions That is JavaScript. My pattern is to be used with PCRE. I added a JavaScript solution.

Comment: @Nostupidquestions I added a linkifying JS code snippet to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the group around and capture what you want to keep. Then start the match with any char except a digit or whitespace char.

The value is in capture group 1.

```
\bhttps?:\/\/\S+|(#[^\s\d#][^\s#]*)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bhttps?:\/\/\S+` match the url
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `#[^\s\d#]` Match `#` followed by any char except `#`, a digit or whitespace char
  - `[^\s#]*` Match 0+ times any char except `#` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OJANgj/1)

```js
const regex = /\bhttps?:\/\/\S+|(#[^\s\d#][^\s#]*)/gm;
const str = `regular text

#1 0:33 - Cool thing <-- this should not match

Tag 2 and tag 3 should be treated as seperate hashtags
#tag1 #tag2#tag3 

Hashtags inside URLs should be ignored

http://example.com/#urlpart

https://example.com#urlpart?s=search`;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[1] !== undefined) console.log(m[1]);
}
```